# How can I create a ForeignKey field only shows when author are current user?

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys, django-admin

How can I create a ForeignKey field only shows **when author are current user**?

I want to create the admin only show the key that the current user create, and the foreignkey is limit by author is current user, too.

**models.py**

```
class costomize_work_type(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,editable=False,null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 10 )
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Work(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(costomize_work_type, on_delete = models.CASCADE,limit_choices_to={'author': current user})
    #other choice
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,editable=False,null=True)
```

**admin.py**

```
class costomize_work_typeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.author = request.user
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(costomize_work_typeAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        return qs.filter(author=request.user)

admin.site.register(costomize_work_type,costomize_work_typeAdmin)

class WorkAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.author = request.user
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(WorkAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        return qs.filter(author=request.user)


admin.site.register(Work,WorkAdmin)
```

Comment: Can you try with `qs.filter(author=request.user, costomize_work_type__author=request.user)`?

Comment: I will try, thanks!

Comment: @bdbd I try it says 'Cannot resolve keyword 'costomize_work_type' into field. Choices are: author, author_id, id, name, work'.

Comment: Ok just change `costomize_work_type` to `work` so: `qs.filter(author=request.user, work__author=request.user)`

Comment: My first suggestion was for `WorkAdmin`. Are you using this on `costomize_work_typeAdmin`?

Comment: Yes. I using this on `costomize_work_typeAdmin`

Comment: Right, so you should use `qs.filter(author=request.user, work__author=request.user)`

Comment: I tried it still no use.

Comment: Are there errors? What is the exact expected output and the actual output?

Comment: I want to do is limit ForeignKey.

Comment: I put it on WorkAdmin it says ' 
Cannot resolve keyword 'work' into field. Choices are: Range, author, author_id, id, limit, name, name_id, time_limit'.

Comment: Just change it to the related model's name

Comment: Thank a lot for your help, I have solved it.

Comment: Great to hear that!

Comment: Your first comment inspired me to change admin setting. I was heading to the wrong way in the beginning. So, thanks very much.